# How to filter timeIndices of Timeseries by intraday-Time efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, time-series

I have a (TimeSeries data) dataframe and it looks like this:

```
                              A1           A2  ...           Z1            Z2
2019-06-17 00:00:01          NaN          NaN  ...          NaN           NaN
2019-06-17 00:01:59          NaN          NaN  ...          NaN           NaN
2019-06-17 00:02:29          NaN          NaN  ...          NaN           NaN 
                         ...          ...  ...          ...           ...
2020-06-17 23:55:01          NaN          NaN  ...          NaN           NaN 
2020-06-17 23:58:45          NaN          NaN  ...          NaN           NaN
2020-06-17 23:59:59          NaN          NaN  ...          NaN           NaN
```

**Question:**

People need to choose by intra- Daytime (00:00:00) need to stay flexible because the seconds can also be up to 59.

how can i extact the indices between a given two timevalues (e.g. 15:00:00, 24:00:00)
But:
only in a specific range of days (e.g. monday - Thursday) ?

*(This is how I extract the range vals:)*

```
timeRangesString = "Mon,Thur,15:00,24:00"               #<== the input
rangeIndices     = pd.Index()


# time ranges:
start_time =  time.strptime( timeRangesString.split(",")[0], "%H:%M:%S")#.dt.strftime("%H:%M", '%H:%M:%S')
if timeRangesString.split(",")[1]=="24:00":   
    end_time    = pd.to_datetime("23:59:59", format="%H:%M:%S")
else: 
    end_time  =  time.strptime( timeRangesString.split(",")[1], "%H:%M")#.dt.strftime("%H:%M",' %H:%M:%S')

# day ranges:
start_dayint  =  time.strptime( timeRangesString.split(",")[2], "%a").tm_wday
end_dayint    =  time.strptime( timeRangesString.split(",")[3], "%a").tm_wday

# ==>   start_time   == 15:00:00
# ==>   end_time     == 23:59:59
# ==>   start_dayint == 0
# ==>   end_dayint   == 3
```

How to extract the indices on the range into "rangeIndices" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) and [`pd.DatetimeIndex.weekday`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html) to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
df.loc[df.index.weekday < 4].between_time('15:00', '00:00')
```

Comment: I tried:                                                                                                  df.loc[df.index.weekday >= start_dayint & df.index.weekday <= end_dayint].between_time(start_time, end_time, include_end=include_end)                                                 it  gives: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Int64Index'"                             the error comes from the weekday part. (I also tried it with 1 & 4, so the input integers arent a problem)

Comment: try : `df.loc [(df.index.weekday> = start_dayint) & (df.index.weekday <= end_dayint)] `